# Multi Sub Array In Php

Tags: php

i have a input `elements` as below

```
        <form method="post" >
1       <input type="text" name="passname[name]" /> <br/> <br/>
2       <input type="text" name="passname[type]" /> <br/> <br/>
3       <input type="text" name="passname[age]" /> <br/> <br/>

1       <input type="text" name="passname[name]" /> <br/> <br/>
2       <input type="text" name="passname[type]" /> <br/> <br/>
3       <input type="text" name="passname[age]" /> <br/> <br/>

        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" /> <br/>
    </form>
```

i want all the `text box` as array in `php`

like Below

```
Passenger Name : passname[name]
Passenger Type : passname[type]
Passenger Age : passname[age]
```

Is this possible with php

form code used in form

```
<input type="text" name="passname[name][]" /> <br/> <br/>
<input type="text" name="passname[type][]" /> <br/> <br/>
<input type="text" name="passname[age][]" /> <br/> <br/>

<input type="text" name="passname[name][]" /> <br/> <br/>
<input type="text" name="passname[type][]" /> <br/> <br/>
<input type="text" name="passname[age][]" /> <br/> <br/>
```

when i submit the form i get this type of array value

```
    array
  'passname' => 
        array
          'name' => 
            array
              0 => string '1' (length=1)
              1 => string '1' (length=1)
          'type' => 
            array
              0 => string '2' (length=1)
              1 => string '2' (length=1)
          'age' => 
            array
              0 => string '3' (length=1)
              1 => string '3' (length=1)
      'send' => string 'Submit' (length=6)
```

how can i do it in for each like blow

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['aa']))
{
    $number = $_POST['1'];
    $text = $_POST['2'];
    foreach($number as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo $val."=".$text[$key]."<br />";
    }
}
?>
<formid="a"name="a"method="post">
<selectid="1[]"name="1[]">
<optionvalue="1">1</option>
<optionvalue="3">3</option>
<optionvalue="2">2</option>
</select>
<inputtype="text"value=""id="2[]"name="2[]"/>
<selectid="1[]"name="1[]">
<optionvalue="1">1</option>
<optionvalue="3">3</option>
<optionvalue="2">2</option>
</select>
<inputtype="text"value=""id="2[]"name="2[]"/>
<inputtype="submit"id="aa"name="aa"value="send now"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It's got nothing to do with PHP. A browser will not pass an array that is not a checkbox. The value in the second text input with the name of `name="passname[name]"` will overwrite the first value passed from the form.

Comment: No, the browser will happily send all input fields. _PHP_ will overwrite the array element with the last value upon parsing the request.

Comment: @user1642610 You should see the answer made by SMka

Comment: One could use: `file_get_contents('php://input');` to bypass php's default behaviour.

Comment: @user1642610: too many updates. think twice what u want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="passname[name][]" /> <br/> <br/>
<input type="text" name="passname[type][]" /> <br/> <br/>
<input type="text" name="passname[age][]" /> <br/> <br/>
```

Comment: i have totaly 3 set's of the above input box but how can i seperate the first input box value

Comment: echo $_POST['passname']['name'][0] :)

Comment: not working i get the value as this i am num 0 and my value varun
i am num 1 and my value kumar

Comment: not working value i got i am num passname and my value
i am num send and my value S

Comment: this is working foreach ($_POST['passname'] as $key => $val) 
 { 
 echo 'My Name Is ' . $val['name'] . ' and My Gender is  '.$val['type'].' my Age is ' . $val['age'] . '<br/>';
 }

Comment: value i got is My Name Is varun and My Gender is male my Age is 20
My Name Is kumar and My Gender is female my Age is 34
My Name Is geeth and My Gender is female my Age is 345

Comment: if possible can you solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241190/search-and-replace-in-php

Answer (score 6):

```
<form method="post" >
       <input type="text" name="passname[name][]" /> <br/> <br/>
       <input type="text" name="passname[type][]" /> <br/> <br/>
       <input type="text" name="passname[age][]" /> <br/> <br/>

       <input type="text" name="passname[name][]" /> <br/> <br/>
      <input type="text" name="passname[type][]" /> <br/> <br/>
       <input type="text" name="passname[age][]" /> <br/> <br/>

        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" /> <br/>
    </form>

<?php
$_POST['passname']['name'];
$_POST['passname']['type'];
$_POST['passname']['age'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the passenger separated, you should build your form like this:

```
<form method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="passname[0][name]" /> <br/> <br/>
  <input type="text" name="passname[0][type]" /> <br/> <br/>
  <input type="text" name="passname[0][age]" /> <br/> <br/>

  <input type="text" name="passname[1][name]" /> <br/> <br/>
  <input type="text" name="passname[1][type]" /> <br/> <br/>
  <input type="text" name="passname[1][age]" /> <br/> <br/>

  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" /> <br/>
</form>
```

then, once submited, your `$_POST` array will look like this one:

```
$_POST == array(
  0 => array(
    'name' => 'XXX',
    'type' => 'XXX',
    'age' => 'XXX',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'name' => 'XXX',
    'type' => 'XXX',
    'age' => 'XXX',
  ),
  'send' => 'Submit',
);
```

where `XXX` represents the user input data.

Comment: without the above mentioned type  is possible

Comment: Is this a question or a comment? Anyway, if you do not require the `type` parameter, simply remove it from the form and the posted data will modify accordingly.